# Delphi (RAD Studio 10) returning error on attempting to refer to edit box

Tags: delphi

So I'm trying to create a login system just for the understanding that doesn't use any web verification or anything, and I'm trying to reference one of the signup edit boxes and getting an error.

Typing:

```
if (edtForeSignup.text  <> '') And (edtSurSignup.text <> '') then
```

returns a red underline on the text boxes. I know they're spelt correctly, and the message just says

```
[dcc32 Error] NotBook.pas(66): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'edtForeSignup'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Either:

1. your Edit box really is not named `edtForeSignup` to begin with.
2. the code you have shown is not actually inside a method of the `TForm` class that owns the `edtForeSignup` object, so there is no `Self` pointer available to reach `edtForeSignup` with.

In that latter case, you would have to use the Form`s global pointer instead, eg:

```
if (Form1.edtForeSignup.text  <> '') And (Form1.edtSurSignup.text <> '') then
```

Comment: Aha! No. 2 fixed it, thanks man. Is there a way of fixing this permanently without having to refer every time?

Comment: Clearly your code that needs the information is not inside the Form class.  You can declare a method in your Form class and move this Signup checking code into it, then it will have a `Self` pointer available to access the Edit boxes with. But your outside code would still need to refer to the Form object to call this new method, eg: `function TForm1.HasSignup: Boolean; begin Result := (edtForeSignup.text  <> '') And (edtSurSignup.text <> ''); end; ... if Form1.HasSignup then...`

Answer (score 1):

E2003 is pretty straightforward and lacking in mystery. As the error says, no identifier with that name can be found in the current scope.

You might think you declared such an identifier, and made it visible in the current scope. But the compiler is the ultimate arbiter. It tells you that you are mistaken. That identifier is not visible in the current scope. You'll need to look at the rest of your code to work out why not.

Comment: Thanks for the snappy response, but I have no idea what you mean, could you maybe dumb it down for me as I only started learning in about November.

Comment: You have to declare an identifier in order to refer to it. The compiler is telling you that you did not declare an identifier named `edtForeSignup`. Or that you did declare an identifier named `edtForeSignup`, but that identifier is not currently visible. Since you did not provide a [mcve] we cannot really say very much more than that.

Comment: Remy said the same as I did ..... If you want help with your actual code, take a note to show us that code. If you want good help, make it so that we can do so without having to apply large amounts of guesswork. Remy did a very good job in guessing what your problem was, and now he is answering your further questions based on more guesswork. But really, we should not need to guess. You'll get better help if you can frame the questions better.

Comment: I think I got where I'm trying to go now, I can ask my teacher tomorrow I just needed a quick fix

Comment: Ah, a quick fix. Well, better the quick fix than some deep learning eh?!!  Not!  If you find my comments irritating, that's intentional. They are meant to make you question your approach.

Comment: I definitely did, I'm gonna go back and re-write it tomorrow when I can sit down and talk with someone properly, I just need this fixed to test the rest of my program, thanks for the help though!